# How can get email address through Facebook login?

Tags: facebook, email

I have integrated Facebook login into my site(codeigniter).I got name, profile URL etc ..but the email address is null...How can I get an email address? I used code from http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make your app request the `email` permission from your user and get an **access token**.
2. Using this **access token**, query the Graph API or use FQL to get the user's email address.

Note: The user may choose to give you a proxified email address when authorising your request for permissions. In this case, the email address you have access to will look something like `{random_string}@facebook.com`.

Refer to the [Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Permissions documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the user_email permission